# choropleth map data not loading for states IN and MN in excel's map powered by bing

Tags: excel, charts, maps

I have a map of the USA in excel - not power BI. I've graphed the qty of shipments to state. The shading and data labels have loaded for all states other than Indiana (IN) and Maine (ME). Since it is not power BI, I can't use the select which locale to remove ambiguity. How should I get this data to load?
I tried adding a country to the data set so that it was formatted as so:

```
| Country |  State Code | Qty |   |   |
|---------|-------------|-----|---|---|
| USA     | NY          | 50  |   |   |
| USA     | ...         | ... |   |   |
| ...     | ...         | ... |   |   |
```

Indiana still doesn't load properly though.

Comment: I need to move this to super-user I think, I was going to delete it and re-ask it but since it has an answer I think that will "count" against me. Can a moderator just migrate it for me instead, or should I just accept the penalty?

Answer (score 0):

Use the state names instead, they are less ambiguous and the data will load properly.